# Why isn't my image aligning bottom?

Tags: html, css

I feel like this is an easy fix but my code isnt working and I'm not sure why.

I want to align the 'voip innovations:your premier wholesale voip carrier' image to the bottom of the div. I made the bottom green for reference.

I tried

```
#cityBackground{
    position:relative;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    background-image:url(../images/city_background_line_vi.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    height:500px;
    background-color:green;

}

    #cityBackground img{

        vertical-align:bottom;
        display:block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;

    }
```

But it doesnt seem to work.

Here is a link to the site

[Link](http://www.voipstreet.com/testSite/index.html)

Is there something I'm missing here?

- EDIT -

Sorry I didnt explain clear enough. I dont want the background-image moved down. I want the logo moved down.

[Picture for reference](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66131799/screenshots/voipTagline.jpg)

Comment: Where do you want the `img`? In the green bar or just above it..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could absolutely position the `img` element relative to to `#cityBackground`.

```
#cityBackground img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -174px;
}
```

Since the `img` width is fixed, you could use `left:50%` and `margin-left:-174px` to center it horizontally. The value `-174px` is half the `img` width.

Comment: This was a good answer. Is there any disadvantage to using absolute position on a responsive website?

Comment: @onTheInternet Not if it's used properly.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS property `background-position` controls where the image sits, not `vertical-align`. Vertical-align is for content. A background image is not content.

Comment: its an <img src> tag though. So doesnt that make it content? Im not talking about the city background. I like that where it is. Im talking about the logo and tagline image

Comment: You don't include your mark-up, and you have a background image in your CSS. Perhaps you should be more specific in your question.

Comment: I apologize. I didnt want to include all the code since I can just link the live site. I included a picture for reference.

Answer (score 0):

this is your code check this one

```
#cityBackground img {   
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 40%;
    right: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try with adding margin-top to the image.

```
#cityBackground img {
display: block;
text-align: center;
width: 348px;
margin:436px auto 0 auto;
}
```